# React map array of objects create container by value and insert objects to that container

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

so I am planning on making events calender, currently I am fetching events which have start value. And my events comes in ascending date format (formated in back end).

My fetch function

```
// Get events
export const getEvents = () => dispatch => {
  dispatch(setEventLoading());
  axios
    .get('http://localhost:3001/events/')
    .then(res => 
      dispatch({
        type: GET_EVENTS,
        payload: res.data
      })
    );
};
```

Event model:

```
const eventSchema = new Schema({
  creator: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  },
  title: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  location: {
    type: String
  },
  photo: {
    type: String
  },
  start: {
    type: Date
  },
  end: {
    type: Date
  },
  going: [
    {
      user: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
      }
    }
  ],
  comments: [
    {
      user: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
      },
      text: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      },
      name: {
        type: String
      },
      date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
      }
    }
  ],
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
});
```

So my plan is to display events in months order.
My UI component where I am mapping my events and displaying it:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import GridList from '@material-ui/core/GridList';
import GridListTile from '@material-ui/core/GridListTile';
import GridListTileBar from '@material-ui/core/GridListTileBar';
import ListSubheader from '@material-ui/core/ListSubheader';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import InfoIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Info';
import ButtonBase from '@material-ui/core/ButtonBase';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
const dateFormat = require('dateformat');
const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
    justifyContent: 'space-around',
    overflow: 'hidden',
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
  },
  gridList: {
    width: 650,
    height: 550,
  },
  icon: {
    color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.54)',
  },
  image: {
    position: 'relative',
    height: 200,
    [theme.breakpoints.down('xs')]: {
      width: '100% !important', // Overrides inline-style
      height: 100,
    },
    '&:hover, &$focusVisible': {
      zIndex: 1,
      '& $imageBackdrop': {
        opacity: 0.15,
      },
      '& $imageMarked': {
        opacity: 0,
      },
      '& $imageTitle': {
        border: '4px solid currentColor',
      },
    },
  },
});


function TitlebarGridList(props) {
  const { classes } = props;

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <GridList cellHeight={180} className={classes.gridList}>
        <GridListTile key="Subheader" cols={2} style={{ height: 'auto' }}>
          <ListSubheader component="div">December</ListSubheader>
        </GridListTile>
        {props.events.map(tile => (

          <GridListTile key={tile._id}>

            <ButtonBase
          focusRipple
          key={tile._id}
          className={classes.image}
          focusVisibleClassName={classes.focusVisible}
          style={{
            width: '100%',
          }}
        >
          <span
            className={classes.imageSrc}
            style={{
              backgroundImage: `url(${tile.photo})`,
            }}
          />
          <span className={classes.imageBackdrop} />
          <span className={classes.imageButton}>
            <Typography
              component="span"
              variant="subheading"
              color="inherit"
              className={classes.imageTitle}
            >
              {dateFormat(tile.start, "dddd dS,  h:MM TT")}
              <span className={classes.imageMarked} />
            </Typography>
          </span>
        </ButtonBase>
            <GridListTileBar
              title={tile.title}
              subtitle={<span>by: {tile._id}</span>}
              actionIcon={
                <IconButton className={classes.icon}>
                  <InfoIcon />
                </IconButton>
              }
            />
          </GridListTile>
        ))}
      </GridList>
    </div>
  );
}

TitlebarGridList.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default withStyles(styles)(TitlebarGridList);
```

So what my plans are looking at this code is to map through events array, then create Subheader which will display month and then append individual event to that month's container by checking objects start date.

My question is what is the cleanest and acceptable way to do it. I can check by substringing events start date to a month which will be 01, 02, 13 (since its iso format i guess) and then checking with if statement while mapping. But the thing is that i need to create max 12 subheaders, and under them append events depending on the start date. What current flow would be in my case. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can simply test if the month from the previous tile is the same as the last after sorting them. Lodash is great for sorting:

```
import _ from 'lodash'

const monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
  "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
let lastMonth = monthNames[0];

function getMonthName(date) {
    return monthNames[date.getMonth()]);
}



{_.sortBy(props.events, ['date']).map(tile => {

    if(getMonthName(tile.date) !== lastMonth) {
        <GridListTile key="Subheader" cols={2} style={{ height: 'auto' }}>
          <ListSubheader component="div">December</ListSubheader>
        </GridListTile>
    }

    return (<GridListTile key={tile._id}>

            <ButtonBase
          focusRipple
          key={tile._id}
          className={classes.image}
          focusVisibleClassName={classes.focusVisible}
          style={{
            width: '100%',
          }}
        >
          <span
            className={classes.imageSrc}
            style={{
              backgroundImage: `url(${tile.photo})`,
            }}
          />
          <span className={classes.imageBackdrop} />
          <span className={classes.imageButton}>
            <Typography
              component="span"
              variant="subheading"
              color="inherit"
              className={classes.imageTitle}
            >
              {dateFormat(tile.start, "dddd dS,  h:MM TT")}
              <span className={classes.imageMarked} />
            </Typography>
          </span>
        </ButtonBase>
            <GridListTileBar
              title={tile.title}
              subtitle={<span>by: {tile._id}</span>}
              actionIcon={
                <IconButton className={classes.icon}>
                  <InfoIcon />
                </IconButton>
              }
            />
          </GridListTile>);

    lastMonth = getMonthName(tile.date);

});
```